# Manual click-once deployment fails on trying to install from it

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce, cruisecontrol.net, mage

I'm trying to get a deployment to work for three environments, dev, test and prod, on the basis of my cruisecontrol.net build server.

I've tried three different angles so far without luck:

1) msbuild, target=Publish, setting urls etc through msbuild properties. Works fine for each of the deployments, but the three installations can't co-exist.

2) msbuild, target=Publish, overwriting the exe.manifest through calls to mage.exe, signing with mage.exe and same thing with the .deployment.

3) msbuild, target=Rebuild, 'manually' copying the debug\bin contents to relevant app.publish subfolder, then same exercise with mage as in 2).

Below is the error-shown-on-application-activation and a batch file running on my build server (adapted to the specific sprint, but that process is less interesting here). It's a bit rough, still a work in progress.
The batch file is run after the solution is rebuild.

Any leads as to what I might try? Thanks,
Anders, Denmark

```
 ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of http://dkapp17/rap1d/Dev/Rap1D_Dev_WPF.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Downloading http://dkapp17/rap1d/dev/rap1d_wpf.application did not succeed.
    + The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

 COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
No transaction error was detected.

 WARNINGS
There were no warnings during this operation.

 OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
* [26-02-2012 21:16:40] : Activation of http://dkapp17/rap1d/Dev/Rap1D_Dev_WPF.application has started.

 ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [26-02-2012 21:16:40] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
    - Downloading http://dkapp17/rap1d/dev/rap1d_wpf.application did not succeed.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
```

And my batch file

```
del "c:\Temp_deploy\*.*" /S/Q
del "c:\ccnet.output\Rap1d-ci\src\Rap1d_WPF\bin\Debug\app.publish\*.*" /S/Q

xcopy c:\ccnet.output\Rap1d-ci\src\Rap1d_WPF\bin\Debug\*.* "c:\Temp_deploy\Rap1D_WPF_2_0_28_3253\" /S
xcopy "c:\Temp_deploy\Rap1D_WPF_2_0_28_3253\*.*" "c:\ccnet.output\Rap1d-ci\src\Rap1d_WPF\bin\Debug\app.publish\Application Files\Rap1D_WPF_2_0_28_3253\" /S



C:\ccnet.output\Rap1d-ci\src\3rdParty\Mage\mage -New Application -Processor x86 -ToFile "c:\ccnet.output\Rap1d-ci\src\Rap1d_WPF\bin\Debug\app.publish\Application Files\Rap1D_WPF_2_0_28_3253\Rap1D1_WPF.exe.manifest" -name "PNRap1D_Dev" -Version "2.0.28.3253" -FromDirectory "c:\ccnet.output\Rap1d-ci\src\Rap1d_WPF\bin\Debug\app.publish\Application Files\Rap1D_WPF_2_0_28_3253"

C:\ccnet.output\Rap1d-ci\src\3rdParty\Mage\mage -Sign "c:\ccnet.output\Rap1d-ci\src\Rap1d_WPF\bin\Debug\app.publish\Application Files\Rap1D_WPF_2_0_28_3253\Rap1D1_WPF.exe.manifest" -CertFile c:\ccnet.output\Rap1d-ci\src\Rap1D_WPF\Dev_TempKey.pfx 



C:\ccnet.output\Rap1d-ci\src\3rdParty\Mage\mage -New Deployment -Processor x86 -Install true -Publisher Grundfos -ProviderUrl http://dkapp17/rap1d/dev/rap1d_wpf.application -ToFile "c:\ccnet.output\Rap1d-ci\src\Rap1d_WPF\bin\Debug\app.publish\Rap1D_Dev_WPF.application" -AppManifest "c:\ccnet.output\Rap1d-ci\src\Rap1d_WPF\bin\Debug\app.publish\Application Files\Rap1D_WPF_2_0_28_3253\Rap1D1_WPF.exe.manifest"
C:\ccnet.output\Rap1d-ci\src\3rdParty\Mage\mage -Sign "c:\ccnet.output\Rap1d-ci\src\Rap1d_WPF\bin\Debug\app.publish\Rap1D_Dev_WPF.application" -CertFile c:\ccnet.output\Rap1d-ci\src\Rap1D_WPF\Dev_TempKey.pfx 

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

The file http://dkapp17/rap1d/dev/rap1d_wpf.application could not be found